# how to using ArrayList in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

i want ArrayList forEach in {N}

how to? help us! plz.

Code for Java

```
public boolean OnPressEvent(ArrayList<MarkerItem> markers){
// in code
}
```

Code for {N}

```
onPressEvent: function(markers: MarkerItem[]) {
// in code (for android)
console.log("length", markers.length) // = undefined
console.log("length", markers.size()) // = 0~n (integer)

// i want run below codes.
markers.forEach(function(marker){
// marker editing....
});
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is:

```
onPressEvent: function(markers: MarkerItem[]) {
  var size = markers.size();
  for (var i=0;i<size;i++) {
    var aMarker = markers.get(i);
    // Do whatever I need to do with this item
  }
});
```